Disk usage in GeoServer showing wrong data
I am using GeoServer 2.20.0
I have a tile layer which is cached in file blob storage.
The file system format on this blob storage is XFS.
I have copied all the tiles from different server in the tile layer folder. The place where I am copying the data has the same XFS file system.
The service is working fine.
When I try to seed missing data for the layer that also works fine. The seeding process ends in 30 minutes, the completion of this process gives me confidence because seeding of the AOI would take 48 hours to generate all the tiles from LOD 0 to 15.
The service looks good in front end as well I have response of tiles in sub seconds.
Its just the disk usage value that is giving me problem with values like    -135,535,407,104.0 B


could it be an integer overflow - how much should it be?

It should be 130 GB
